# making a floating div with css and anything in it

Tags: css

i wanna make a floating menu kind of like facebook with css with no animation just straight up attached to the top all the time, i have this div

```
   <div id="topmenu">

<ul class="topmenu_buttons">
<li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="Change_Location"><a href="#">loaction</a></li>
<li class="Help_Topmenu"><a href="#">help</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

and i have my css file already made but empty but i would like a quick explanation on how to arrange these three links in css as a list with a small normal font in a list fashion one on top of the other all inside a black div the links located to the left but a few pixels to the right from the left and also 
if its possible to apply the floating css effect (((postion:fixed ))))on the div so it applies to everything on it, if not possible then how to apply it also for the links
also how to make it look like kind of like facebook but black and slighter bigger thicker i been trying with my css notes but it never works for me i dont know what im doing wrong

thank you i basically want the css code for a external file not inline style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#menu {
    postion:fixed;
    top:0;
    background:#3B5998; same color as fb has
    width:100%;
    height:46px;
    left:0;
    z-index:2; //give this so, your header or menu will not get under content!
}
```

Comment: The id of his menu is `topmenu` and "make it look like kind of like facebook but **black** and slighter bigger thicker".

Comment: @OneMore who you are talking with ? me? :)

Answer (score 2):

That should do everything you want to do:

```
#topmenu{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    background:#000;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
}
```

Comment: its not working, it appeared black so your code is working however it doesnt float??

Comment: never  mind you just mispelled position you typed postion thank you alot bro, thank you

Comment: well, add z-index also buddy @user1936170